# Instead of storing values to local storage want to store values in Redux how can i Do?

Tags: reactjs

Hello  I am using class component in react JS.Instead of storing values to local storage store values in Redux how can i Do?How can we implement this in react JS. Below I am sharing my code.Please check my where I am doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Step5 extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {estimated:'1-2'}
        this.handleChange  = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        const { estimated, value } = event.target;
        console.log('JJF',event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: event.target.value
        });
      };
      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
         var step5  =  this.state.estimated;
        
         console.log('estimated', JSON.stringify(step5))
         console.log('step5',step5);
         localStorage.setItem('step5', step5);
        const data = {
           id: new Date(),
           step5:step5
        }
        
        this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_STEP5',data});
        window.open("/Step6" , "_self");  
     }

      
    render(){
        const {value} =this.state;
        return(  
            <div>
            <Header />           
              <section className="planing_outer">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h1>{value} fff</h1>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="inner_heading">
                            <h4>How big is your event?</h4>
                        </div>   
                        <div className="row">  
                    <div className="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                        <div className="text_outer"># of Estimated Attendees</div>
                        <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                            <div className="even_box1">
                            <input type="radio" className="ischeck" id="flexCheckDefault" checked={this.state.selectedOption==="1-20"} value="1-20" name="estimated" onChange={this.handleChange}/><h3>1-20</h3>
                                    
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                            <div className="even_box1">
                            <input type="radio" className="ischeck" id="flexCheckDefault" checked={this.state.selectedOption==="21-50"} value="21-50" name="estimated" onChange={this.handleChange}/><h3>21-50</h3>
                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                            <div className="even_box1">
                            <input type="radio" className="ischeck" id="flexCheckDefault" value="50+" checked={this.state.selectedOption==="50+"} name="estimated" onChange={this.handleChange}/><h3>50+</h3>
                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>   
                        <div className="text_outer atten">You can always edit it later</div>            
                        <div className="btn_outer">
                            
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'> Continue </button>
                        {/* <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' disabled={btnDisabled}  onClick={redirectNewStep}> Continue </button> */}
                        {/* <a href="Step6" type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Continue</a> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </section>
             
            </div>
            )
            
    } 

}
export default connect()(Step5);
```

In this I am using radio button on submit how we check radio button is checked not. If check store their value in redux and local storage .

Comment: Since you are setting the checked prop of the radio button like this `{this.state.selectedOption==="50+"}`, you can use the same checks within your onSubmit function to see which radio button is checked and which isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your selected value in `selectedOption`, retrieving that state in `hadleSubmit` should work fine:

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const selected = this.state.selectedOption;
    if (!selected) {
        alert('Please select an estimate')
        return
    }
    localStorage.setItem('step5', selected);
    const data = {
      id: new Date(),
      step5: selected,
    };

    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_STEP5', data });
    window.open('/Step6', '_self');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the **value** of selected radio button in the state variable `selectedOption`. You are assigning event.target.value to selectedOption, so selectedOption will either have value '21-50' or '50+'  You just need to check if selectedOption is defined in your `handleSubmit` function

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var step5  =  this.state.selectedOption;
    if(step5)
         localStorage.setItem('step5', step5);
    const data = {
        id: new Date(),
        step5:step5
    }
    this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_STEP5',data});
    window.open("/Step6" , "_self");  
}
```

Comment: How can i set state and get state instead of local store redux react js

Comment: @NidhiMahajan do you want to store the value is localStorage or in a redux store?

Comment: Previously i stored values in local storage but now i want to stoe value in redux store (setItems ) and how to get stored values in multi step form

Comment: Your question says you want to store values in localStorage. The accepted answer is also for storing values in the localStorage. Kindly update the question as required so that people can answer appropriately